# Can someone tell me why it doesn't show anything in console?? I want to get values of inputs. Do I have to use form?

Tags: javascript, console

```
<input type="text" name="" id="num1" placeholder="number1">

<input type="text" name="" id="num2" placeholder="number2"> 

<button type="submit" id="add">Add</button>

<script>

let value1 = document.getElementById('num1');

let value2 = document.getElementById('num2'); 

let submit = document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('onclick', getValue);

function getValue(){

let newValue1 = value1.value;

let newValue2 = value2.value;

console.log(newValue1 + newalue2);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code with using ``` ```

Comment: `addEventListener('click', getValue);`

Comment: Thankyou so much now its working

Comment: Btw what is the exact difference between click and onclick?

Comment: i added description in my answer, @JPabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener('onclick', getValue)` should be updated to `addEventListener('click', getValue)`

```js
let value1 = document.getElementById('num1');

let value2 = document.getElementById("num2");

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click', getValue);

function getValue() {

  let newValue1 = value1.value;

  let newValue2 = value2.value;

  console.log(newValue1 + newValue2);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="num1" placeholder="number1">
<input type="text" name="" id="num2" placeholder="number2">

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

or use `<button id="add" onclick="getValue()">Add</button>` without `addEventListener`

```js
let value1 = document.getElementById('num1');

let value2 = document.getElementById("num2");

function getValue() {

  let newValue1 = value1.value;

  let newValue2 = value2.value;

  console.log(newValue1 + newValue2);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="num1" placeholder="number1">
<input type="text" name="" id="num2" placeholder="number2">

<button id="add" onclick="getValue()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou soo much. I understood. I'll refer some more